# Attach to Process Extremely Slow To Open

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, attach-to-process

When I click on Attach to Process in either VS2010 or VS2012 it takes about 10 minutes for the "Attach to Process" window to open. While waiting for it to open VS is unresponsive, I have to End Process from task manager to do anything else. Can anyone please give me a solution for this problem? It is extremely frustrating.

Comment: It takes some time but 10 minutes... too much. Please check if your memory usage is too high in task manager and system is thrashing.

Comment: Consider using trace/debug statements. Often that get's you 80% of what you wanted to know from step through and doesn't require attaching.